# How to chain promises within a loop and also wait for the completion of all the loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, promise

I'm iterating over an object, executing an ajax call for each iteration.
I need to:

1. Execute the ajax calls in order
2. Do something only after all ajax calls are done.

I'm able to achieve each of the above goals separately, but not both of them.

Below is a simplified version of my code.

Using `promises.push` together with `Promises.all` achieves the goal of waiting for the loop's completion.

Using `return my_ajax_fn()` (commented out in the code below) achieves the goal of executing the calls in order.

But how do I achieve both?

```
function my_ajax_fn(index, value){
    return $.ajax({
    url: site_url,
    type: "POST",            
    success: function(data) { 
        // do some stuff
        }});
}


function test_done() {
    var promises = [];
    
    for (const [index, value] of Object.entries(answers)){
        if (index!=0) {
            p1 = p1.then(function() { 
            promises.push(my_ajax_fn(index, value));
//          return my_ajax_fn(index, value);
            });
           };
    };
    
    Promise.all(promises)
    .then(() => {
        // do stuff after all the ajax calls are done
    })
    .catch((e) => {
        // handle errors here
    });
    
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to sequence a series of asynchronous operations is to use `async/await`.  That will also make it easy to know when they are done:

```
async function test_done() {
    for (const [index, value] of Object.entries(answers)){
        if (index != 0) {
            await my_ajax_fn(index, value);
        }
    }
    console.log("all done now");
}
```

From outside of that function, it returns a promise so you can use that to know when it's done too:

```
test_done().then(() => {
    console.log("all done");
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can chain the Promise by returning a Promise in the callback:

```
p1 = p1.then(()=>my_ajax_fn(index_value))
```

That causes the Promise then to chain on the returned Promise, which is the Promise returned by `my_ajax_fn()`.

Also consider using [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) syntax. Syntax could be written as:
`async function testDone(){ }` and `await my_ajax_fn()`
Allows a syntax similar to writing synchronous code that tends to be cleaner, easier to read and understand, as well as generally being more performant than [hand-written promise code](https://v8.dev/blog/fast-async).

Comment: So if I declare `async function testDone(){}` and within it use `for await` instead of `for`, any code written below the loop will wait for the loop to complete before it is executed?

Comment: it will wait for the Promise (or async) following the await to resolve before continuing.  for-await-of will await on each Promise/async returned from the iterable after `of`.  Like iterating on Promises (or async).